# Summing transformative data using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Say I have this example XML:

```
<cart>
    <box>
        <food type="apple" quantity="3"/>
        <food type="orange" quantity="2"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <food type="apple" quantity="6"/>
        <food type="orange" quantity="1"/>
    </box>
</cart>
```

If apples cost $1 and oranges cost $2, I would like to get the value of the sum of the cart into an XSLT variable (in the case the sum would be $7 + $8 = $15).

```
<xsl:variable name=cartsum>
    //Something in here to iterate over the food in all the boxes
    //in the cart, transform them to dollars, and add them together
</xsl:variable>`
```

I know I can use `xsl:template`'s and use `xsl:choose`'s to get something like the string "((3 * 1) + (2 * 2)) + ((6 * 1) + (1 * 2))", but how do I get that sum into a variable that I can use in other `xsl:if` evaluations?

---

Also, another related question, I would like to assign to a different variable the most expensive box (i.e. the max of the box values) as well, which in this case it would be $8. Hopefully both solutions (sum and max) can be achieved the same way.

---

BTW, I am using Saxon-HE 9.6.0.4N as my XSLT engine

Comment: Where are the prices coming from? Are they supposed to be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, the prices are hardcoded in the stylesheet. So I am fine with the "code" in the sheet being the one that knows the prices for apples and the prices for oranges.

Comment: Ok, so what is missing from my answer?

Comment: Nothing, I was just testing it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="priceList">
    <food type="apple">1</food>
    <food type="orange">2</food>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:key name="price" match="food" use="@type" />
    
<xsl:template match="/cart">
    <xsl:variable name="boxes">
        <xsl:for-each select="box">
            <box value="{sum(food/(@quantity * key('price', @type, $priceList)))}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <result>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$boxes"/>
        <sum>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum($boxes/box/@value)"/>
        </sum>
        <max>
            <xsl:value-of select="max($boxes/box/@value)"/>
        </max>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your XML example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <box value="7"/>
   <box value="8"/>
   <sum>15</sum>
   <max>8</max>
</result>
```